# Linear Search in python

Tags: python

```
def search_linear(x,y):
  n = len( x )
  for i in range(n):

  if theValue[i] == y:
        return True

  return false

def main():
  mainValues =int( input("enter the nos first"))
  mV = mainValues.list()

  trgt =int( input('enter a single number to be found in the list'))
  def search_linear(mainValues, trgt)
```

This is a simple linear search program I wrote. When run, it says `invalid syntax` on line 17, which points to `trgt = ...`. 
I do not understand where I am going wrong.

I write the searching function and in main function assign the values. Such a simple program

Comment: In addition to not using def, ensure your whitespace is syntactically correct. The `return false` should be indented to where the for loop starts. (I can't tell if that was an error when copying here or in your actual program)

Comment: It was a posting mistake, otherwise it would have said `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: false should be written as False. Var theValue is unknown in the function search_linear. mainValues.list() 'int' object has no attribute 'list'... Remove def from the last def search_linear(mainValues, trgt). tbh it looks like copy & paste without understanding of what's going on!

Comment: The whole function body could be written as `return y in x`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `def` when you call a function. Just use `search_linear(mainValues, trgt)`.

`def` is only needed when you specify the **definition** of a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Tried my hand at a code by using simple keywords, no functions etc. Ideal for beginners.
ls=[]
n=input("Enter the number of elements in the list:")
for i in range(0,n,1):
    b=input("Enter the elements:")
    ls.append(b)
print(ls)
element_to_be_searched=input("Enter the element to be searched:")
for j in range(0,n,1):
    if ls[j]==element_to_be_searched:
        if j+1==1:
            print("Search is successful and requested element is the 1st element")
            break
        elif j+1==2:
            print("Search is successful and requested element is the 2nd element")
            break
        elif j+1==3:
            print("Search is successful and requested element is the 3rd element")
            break
        elif j+1>3:
            print("Search is successful and requested element is the ",j+1,"th element")
            break
    else:
         print("Sorry,could not find the item you are looking for!")
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
usernames = ['AB','CD','EF','GH','IJ','KL']
passwords = ['12','23','56','78','98','76']

def search (x,y):
    n = len(x)
    for i in range(n):
         if usernames[i] == y:
             print("It is here!")
             return True
         else:
             print ("Incorrect!")

mainValues = input("Enter the username")

search(usernames,mainValues)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def LinearSearch(array, targetNumber):
    for i in range (0,5):
        array[i] == targetNumber:
            print("The number %d does exist in the list." %(targetNumber))
        array[i] != targetNumber:
            print("The number %d does not exist in the list." %(targetNumber))

import random
random_number = []
for l in range (0,5):
    random_number.append(random.randint(1,100))

# Algorithm Sort
for i in range(0, 5):
        for j in range (5-1, -1, -1):
            if random_number[j] < random_number[j-1]:
                new_value = random_number[j-1]
                random_number[j-1] = random_number[j]
                random_number[j] = new_value
            if j == 1:
                break
```